# I am trying to build my game in unity but it is giving me an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assets/Scripts/ThirdPersonCamera.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

im so confused on why i am getting this error.....

why is this happening?

Comment: It appears that you're missing a reference.

Comment: Try UnityEngine instead

Comment: Check the second answer here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/316805/unityeditor-namespace-not-found.html Sounds like you can't build the game using any Editor-specific scripts.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks The most probably he is not missing a reference. "UnityEditor" namespace is simply not available in builds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because UnityEditor namespace is available only in editor scripts, that are located in `Assets/Editor` folder; or if you are running your game in the editor. If you need some functionality while running your game in the editor, you can do this:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

class Script: MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // Editor specific part here
#endif
    }
}
```